# Is there a way of handling multiple xsd versions with xmlBeans?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xmlbeans

I know that I can compile multiple xsd files in a single jar. I've tried using different namespaces which only takes me half way through my goal. This way I can parse the correct schema but I want this to be transparent to my users which will receive the xmlBeans object that I've parsed.

They don't have to know which version of xml file is currently present on the system. I would need a super class for every xsd version to achieve this.

Could this be done with xmlBeans?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, if you have a com namespace and a com.v1 and com.v2 namespace and you have an xsd element called EmployeeV1 in com.v1 and EmployeeV2 in com.v2. 
You want to a super class called Employee in the com namespace which you want to return to your caller?

Do you think EmployeeV1 and EmployeeV2 could extend from Employee in your xsd? Then maybe when you generate you will get the class hierarchy that represents your xsd.

If that doesn't work, (i haven't used xmlbeans in years now), you might have to create your own domain object and make your callers consume that. That might be worth the effort, since to me it looks like you handle the parsing of an XML that other people rely on, you could abstract all other users from the structure of the XML (which is in flux) by having an intermediary domain object.